# Use SSL certificate with a Node library referenced by a Deno script

Tags: node.js, typescript, deno

I wrote a node.js library that I'm using in a Deno (typescript) script:

```
import * as Adp from "npm:@craibuc/adp-workforce-now";

import { load } from "https://deno.land/std@0.205.0/dotenv/mod.ts";
const env = await load();
    
const client = new Adp.Client(env['ADP_CERTIFICATE'], env['ADP_PRIVATE_KEY'])    
const credentials = await client.authenticate(env['ADP_CLIENT_ID'], env['ADP_CLIENT_SECRET'])
```

This results in an error that indicates that the SSL certificate is invalid or not present.

If I use the same code from within a Node.js script, with the exact same credentials, it works as expected.

The certificate and key resemble this:

```
ADP_CERTIFICATE="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
ADP_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

This is the code that does the authentication in the module:

```
authenticate = async (client_id, client_secret) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const body = JSON.stringify({
            client_id: client_id,
            client_secret: client_secret,
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        });

        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': body.length
        }

        const options = {
            hostname: 'api.adp.com',
            path: '/auth/oauth/v2/token',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            cert: this.certificate,
            key: this.private_key,
        };

        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {

            let data = [];
        
            res.on('data', chunk => {
                data.push(chunk);
            });
            
            res.on('end', () => {

                JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(data).toString());

                if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {

                    const error = new Error(res.statusCode)
                    error.details = json
                    reject(error)

                }
                else {
                    resolve(json); 
                }

            });

        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
            reject(e.message);
        });

        if (method == 'POST') { req.write(body); }

        req.end();

    });

}
```

What am I not understanding?